# Unckecked method invocation warning on Collections.sort()

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, unchecked

I want to sort a `List<MyType>` received as a an argument :

```
static void doSomething(List<MyType> arg) {
    Collections.sort(arg);
}
```

...but I get this warning :

```
Unchecked method 'sort(List<T>)' invocation
```

Here's `MyType` :

```
class MyType implements Comparable {
    private int number;

    public MyType(int n) {
        number = n;
    }

    public int compareTo(MyType b) {
        return Integer.compare(number, b.number);
    }
}
```

I can suppress this warning, but I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't seem to mach with the warning. Please show the exact code.

Comment: You should write a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: it's most likely because `MyType` doesn't use the generic `Comparable<MyType>`. so to remove the warning just implement the generic `Comparable` interface.

Comment: That's the exact code that raises the warning, with `MyType` and `doSomething` renamed. Not sure how I can make it more "Minimal" than that, but I'll add MyType's implementation for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Aominè had it right : `MyType` implemented `Comparable` instead of `Comparable<MyType>`. The warning is gone now that I've changed this.

Comment: on top of that, reason being is because the way `Collections.sort(List<T>)`  is defined is that it expects the type argument `T` to implement `Comparable<? super T>` hence you were getting the warning when you didn't implement the generic `Comparable` interface.

Comment: see the full definition of the method here --> [**Collections.sort(List<T>)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)